# How probable is that a randomly typed 47 digit odd integer is a prime?

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, primality-test

So, I have been playing around with prime numbers, I have installed `gmp` and `gmpy2`

`gmpy2` has a function `gmpy2.is_prime` for primality testing (non deterministic) which uses the Miller-Rabin primality test.

Now to test the speed of `gmpy2.is_prime` I typed some random digits '1245268798719487981976914598618498569816481948' and added a '3' to the end so that the number is not *even*. It took it milliseconds to get the result and to my surprise,

```
In [18]: gmpy2.is_prime(12452687987194879819769145986184985698164819483)
Out[18]: True
```

What? really? the number I randomly typed is a prime?

To make sure `is_prime` wasn't returning true for every other number I added a few digits and expectedly

```
In [25]: gmpy2.is_prime(124526879871948798197691459861849856981648139483)
Out[25]: False

In [26]: gmpy2.is_prime(12452687987194879819769145986555184985698164819483)
Out[26]: False
```

I was blown away, but now, I am curious. What is the probability of this happening?

More specifically, What is the probability that a randomly selected odd 47 digit number passes Miller-Rabin primality test?

Did I just get really really lucky?

Comment: Less than 40%, since any number ending in 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, or 0 will not be prime, but actually much lower than that.

Comment: @torazaburo that is **really** optimistic

Comment: @StephenC thanks... that answers it, I did not get that lucky either log(12452687987194879819769145986555184985698164819483) = 113.046.., 1 in 113 is not *that* lucky...

Comment: The 1 / log(x) probability estimate includes even numbers. The probability that an odd number is prime is about 2 / log(x).

Comment: If you made sure that the last digit is $1,3,7 \ or\ 9$ you have a slightly higher probability, about $\frac{2.5}{\ln(x)}$ , which is about $1$ out of $42$ in your case.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) there are approximately
$$10^{47}/\ln(10^{47}) - 10^{46}/\ln(10^{46}) = 8.296\cdot10^{44}$$ 47-digit primes and
$$9\cdot10^{46}/2$$ odd 47-digit numbers. So the probability is approximately  $8.296\cdot10^{44}/4.5\cdot10^{46} = 0.018$.

Without numbers with 5 as last digit the probability is approximately $8.296\cdot10^{44}/3.6\cdot10^{46} = 0.023$.

Edit:

The values with the somewhat better approximation $1/\ln(x)$ for the probability that a random integer not greater than $x$ is prime are

$0.01868$ for odd number in the given range and

$0.02335$ for odd numbers not ending with 5.

Comment: Li(x) would be a better approximation to pi(x), and OP also excluded numbers ending in 5, so you need to divide by 2.5.

Comment: The question was "What is the probability that a randomly selected odd 47 digit number passes Miller-Rabin primality test?" (Strong pseudoprimes are rare enough to neglect them.)